# Cant boot to bios on external monitor on all in one

Tags: boot, bios, desktop, all-in-one

I have a Dell inspiration 14" 3455 series all in one with a cracked screen that I cracked a few years ago. I recently found it and want to install linux on the machine but to to that I need to go into the boot manager and or bios. But the bios only displays on the cracked screen of the all in one and since it isn't a laptop I cant do the trick where you cover the magnet sensor with another magnet. Can anyone suggest a way I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

BIOS needs the built-in screen (in your case the All in One screen) to start.

You will need to repair the screen.

There is no other way for this, not even a dock of some sort here (for an All on One model).

Repairing an All in One screen may be expensive, so you may need to live with the existing BIOS until you can replace the screen.

Comment: But just asking, could I remove the screen so it defaults to the monitor as a last resort?

Comment: No, I am quite certain that will not work. You can try, but BIOS will look for the screen built in.

Comment: Indeed it needs more than "removing the screen", some contacts have to be shorted and even that isn't guaranteed. The problem then becomes obvious: If a person knows how to do it safely that person wouldn't be here asking this question. So, at the end of the day, the advice is always the one in this answer.